# How to keep DataFrame / column and index names after calculation with np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 different `pd.DataFrames`:

`dailyRtn`

```
date         A          B               C                                   
2017-12-25  0.069392    0.124916    0.119108
2017-12-26  0.020000    0.100000    0.080000
2017-12-27  1.000000    1.200000    1.500000
```

`averageofP`

```
date         A          B               C                                   
2017-12-25  0.059392    0.894916    0.419108
2017-12-26  0.021000    0.100000    0.990000
2017-12-27  1.500000    1.100000    1.800000
```

Which can be reproduced with the code below:

```
dailyRtn = pd.DataFrame([["2017-12-25",  0.069392,    0.124916,    0.119108],
                         ["2017-12-26",  0.020000,    0.100000,    0.080000],
                         ["2017-12-27",  1.000000,    1.200000,    1.500000]],
                        columns = ["date", "A", "B", "C"])

averageofP = pd.DataFrame([["2017-12-25",  0.059392,    0.894916,    0.419108],
                           ["2017-12-26",  0.021000,    0.100000,    0.990000],
                           ["2017-12-27",  1.500000,    1.100000,    1.800000]],
                          columns = ["date", "A", "B", "C"])
```

I'm trying to make a conditional calculation using the 2 df above:

```
downsideDev = np.where(dailyRtn < averageofP, dailyRtn, "")
```

My goal is to have a new `DataFrame (downsideDev)` that looks similar to above tables, but with values that come from my conditional argument with `np.where`. I'm aware `np.where` creates an `ndarray` so I did:

```
downsideDev = pd.DataFrame(downsideDev)
```

However, when I take a look at downsideDev my former columns: A, B, C etc. and dates: 2017-12-27 etc. are all gone and are simple integers + it's not a DataFrame anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the expected output? On related note, numpy.where output is ndarray or tuples and thus if you expect the output to be a pandas DataFrame then you need to create one from the resulting array.

Comment: The expected output is a dataframe like above. I understand output is ndarray. when I do: downsideDev = pd.DataFrame(downsideDev), it removes the index and column names, which I want to keep. Keep in mind I have over 20 columns and many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `set_index` and then include `index` and `columns` in your dataframe constructor.

```
dailyRtn = dailyRtn.set_index('date')
averageofP = averageofP.set_index('date')

downsideDev = np.where(dailyRtn < averageofP, dailyRtn, "")
downsideDev_df = (pd.DataFrame(downsideDev, index=dailyRtn.index, columns=dailyRtn.columns)
                    .reset_index())

print(downsideDev_df)
```

Output:

```
         date     A                    B                    C
0  2017-12-25        0.12491600000000001  0.11910799999999999
1  2017-12-26  0.02                                      0.08
2  2017-12-27   1.0                                       1.5
```

Comment: Sorry just had to do something, all done :)!. can't be viewed cause I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: downsideDev = np.where(dailyRtn < averageofP, dailyRtn, "");
downsideDev_df = pd.DataFrame(downsideDev, columns=dailyRtn.columns);
downsideDev_df["date"] = dailyRtn["date"]                                                   feel your answer can be modified into three lines like this

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this without `np.where` which leave out the information you need. The approach is native in pandas: a conditional selection plus `fillna`.

```
dailyRtn = pd.DataFrame([["2017-12-25",  0.069392,    0.124916,    0.119100],
                         ["2017-12-26",  0.020000,    0.100000,    0.080000],
                         ["2017-12-27",  1.000000,    1.200000,    1.500000]],
                         columns = ["date", "A", "B", "C"])

averageofP = pd.DataFrame([["2017-12-25",  0.059392,    0.894916,    0.419108],
                           ["2017-12-26",  0.021000,    0.100000,    0.990000],
                           ["2017-12-27",  1.500000,    1.100000,    1.800000]],
                           columns = ["date", "A", "B", "C"])

# select value in dailyRtn with a condition
downsideDev = dailyRtn[dailyRtn < averageofP]
downsideDev.fillna("", inplace=True) # fill out nan part with ""
downsideDev["date"] = dailyRtn["date"] # add back "date" that were replaced to ""
```

[image]